# Adding "Relevant Courses" Section to Jake's Resume Template

Tags: cv

I am a beginner in Latex, and am trying to create a resume using the "Jake's Resume" template (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/jakes-resume/syzfjbzwjncs).
I am currently trying to add a "Relevant Coursework section" in the education section, which lists the courses I take that are of my major:[image]

but find it difficult, as the template uses custom commands. I think that the custom command corresponding to the education section is one of these:

```
\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-2pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheading}[2]{
    \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textit{\small#1} & \textit{\small #2} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-7pt}
}
```

But am not sure which, and how to modify it to include a relevant coursework section. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Like in this resume:
[image]

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Was the code useful?

Answer (score 2):

This example will help you to to get started.

The new command `\resumeSubSubheadingLeft` will behave like you requested. It takes 2 mandatory arguments like:

```
\resumeSubSubheadingLeft
    {Relevant Coursework}
    {Operating System, Data Structures, Analysis of Algorithms, Artificial Inteligence,  Machine Learning, Networking, Databases, ...}
```

[image: c]

Put this code before `\section{Experience}`

```
%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  RESUME STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{calc} % added
\newcommand{\resumeSubSubheadingLeft}[2]{% % added
\begin{description}[leftmargin=!,labelwidth=\widthof{\small\bfseries #1}]
    \item[\small #1]{\textit{\small  #2}}
\end{description}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Huge \scshape Jake Ryan} \\ \vspace{1pt}
    \small 123-456-7890 $|$ \href{mailto:x@x.com}{\underline{jake@su.edu}} $|$ 
    \href{https://linkedin.com/in/...}{\underline{linkedin.com/in/jake}} $|$
    \href{https://github.com/...}{\underline{github.com/jake}}
\end{center}


%-----------EDUCATION-----------
\section{Education}

\resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
    {Southwestern University}{Georgetown, TX}
    {Bachelor of Arts in Computer Science, Minor in Business}{Aug. 2018 -- May 2021}
    
    \resumeSubSubheadingLeft% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    {Relevant Coursework}{Operating System, Data Structures, Analysis of Algorithms, Artificial Inteligence,  Machine Learning, Networking, Databases, ...}
    
\resumeSubHeadingListEnd

%-----------EXPERIENCE----------
```

Comment: Is it possible to just have a list (not vertical) after the Major, not using the custom commands if that is simpler? So that the education section would look like this:

Relevant Coursework: class 1, class 2, class 3, ... (All underneath the "bachelor of arts in x" part)

Comment: @dphil1 Is it possible for you add a figure (even handmade) of how would like to  the Coursework look like?

Comment: Something like the one in this format:https://www.overleaf.com/project/611d17495165224b16622db3

except instead of "courses" it is "relevant coursework" and in bold

Comment: I edited the original post and put the picture at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!